# Should community wiki SO questions be moved to Meta?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, meta, community-wiki

Since the "community wiki" questions on Stack Overflow don't really seem to be in line with Jeff's ideology for the site, should thye all be moved to Meta? It seems like a better place for discussion/subjective questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, not at all. Meta is for discussion of StackOverflow itself, not just a garbage dump for anything you might not think is valid discussion on StackOverflow.

There are lots of items on SO that are CW and are perfectly legit.

I suggest that you read up more on what Community Wiki actually is and how it is used in StackOverflow: [What Are Community Wiki Posts On StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 10):

Not *all* wiki questions from SO are out of line with the SO ideology. Even though some are designed for fun, they can still be very programming-related.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think so. The community wiki questions on SO, while perhaps not as straightforward as non-CW questions, are still (however vaguely) programming-related or they'd get closed just as well. Meta is not for programming-related questions, but for discussion about SO. Thus they belong on SO, not meta.

There may be *some* questions however that do belong here, but certainly not *all*.